# SQL to Conditional Retrieval of Records - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am trying to achieve the below via SQL in SQL Server.

I have a source table which has the following records:

[image: screenshot of source and target data]

- I should always retrieve the `RCD` 6 and 7 records if they exist
- For `RCD` 8 and 9, I need to check if for the same `PKey`:

  - if `Rkey`s are same, if yes, then I need to retrieve anyone record only
- for `RCD` 8 and 9 for the same `PKey` if `Rkey` is different then I need to retrieve both.

I tried doing it, but I am not getting any idea on how to do it, can anyone suggest any logic on how to achieve this in SQL for SQL Server.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  A clearer explanation would also help.

Comment: I have added a image of source and target data , I was not able to align the data in text format so I posted a screenshot

Comment: Please clarify your criteria - I don't understand why rows `RAKey=103` and `RAKey=501`  should be ignored.

Comment: for RCD in (8,9), if for the same Pkey, Rkey is same, then I need to retrieve anyone record only. It can be RCD = 9 or RCD = 9

Comment: Your description does not match expected output. Why `RAKey = 501` is not in the output? `Pkey` is same but `RKey` is not

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions to get the base information you want.  The rest is just logic:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(rkey) over (partition by rcd, pkey) as min_rkey,
             max(rkey) over (partition by rcd, pkey) as max_rkey,
             row_number() over (partition by rcd, pkey, rkey order by rkey) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where rcd in (6, 7) or
      ( (rcd in (8, 9) and min_rkey = max_rkey and seqnum = 1) or
        (rcd in (8, 9) and min_rkey <> max_rkey)
      );
```

EDIT:

I suspect you want more than on `pkey` for the 8/9 conditions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(rkey) over (partition by rcd, pkey) as min_rkey,
             max(rkey) over (partition by rcd, pkey) as max_rkey,
             row_number() over (partition by rcd, pkey, rkey order by rkey) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by rcd, pkey) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where rcd in (6, 7) or
      ( (rcd in (8, 9) and cnt > 1 and min_rkey = max_rkey and seqnum = 1) or
        (rcd in (8, 9) and cnt > 1 and min_rkey <> max_rkey)
      );
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I just tried the sql, but some how the sql is returning to  many rows

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correctly, this is what you looking for:

```
SELECT RAKey, RCD, Pkey, Rkey, Akey
    FROM Source s
        WHERE s.RCD IN (6,7)
UNION
SELECT RAKey, RCD, Pkey, Rkey, Akey FROM
(SELECT 
row_number() over(partition by Pkey order by newid()) as rowID,
*
    FROM Source s2
        WHERE RCD IN (8,9)
        AND (EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Source WHERE Pkey = s2.Pkey AND s2.RCD = 8 AND RCD = 9 AND RKey = s2.Rkey)
        OR EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Source WHERE Pkey = s2.Pkey AND s2.RCD = 9 AND RCD = 8 AND RKey = s2.Rkey))
        ) s2
        WHERE rowID = 1
UNION
SELECT RAKey, RCD, Pkey, Rkey, Akey
    FROM Source s3
        WHERE RCD IN (8,9)
        AND (EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Source WHERE Pkey = s3.Pkey AND s3.RCD = 8 AND RCD = 9 AND RKey <> s3.Rkey)
        OR EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Source WHERE Pkey = s3.Pkey AND s3.RCD = 9 AND RCD = 8 AND RKey <> s3.Rkey))
```

And also, your target's illustration is contradict with the criteria you have below:

- for RCD 8 and 9 for the same PKey if Rkey is different then I need to retrieve both.

it is supposedly to show both 401 and 501 since the RKey is different as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qLy5.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [SOURCE] WHERE RCD IN (6,7)

UNION ALL
SELECT H.RAKEY,H.RCD,H.pkey,H.rkey
FROM
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY PKEY,rkey,Value ORDER BY RAKEY) 
 RNO,A.*
 FROM
 (
   SELECT  H.RAKEY,H.RCD,H.pkey,H.rkey,CASE WHEN H.RAKEY < K.RAKEY THEN 
   H.RAKEY ELSE K.RAKEY END Value
   FROM [SOURCE] H
   LEFT JOIN [SOURCE] K
   ON H.pkey = K.pkey AND H.rkey = K.rkey AND H.RCD <> K.RCD AND K.RCD IN 
   (8,9)
   WHERE H.RCD IN (8,9) 
  )A
 )H WHERE H.RNO = 1
 ORDER BY 1`
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help.

Thanks Ramya, this query is working fine.

Just one more doubt, how can we compare the previous row and current row in this query.


What I am trying to do is, if PKey and RKey values are same for RCD 6 and RCD 8 and 9, I want to keep the details of RCD6 and discard rest of the details.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT H.RAKEY,H.RCD,H.pkey,H.rkey
FROM
 (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY PKEY,rkey,Value ORDER BY RCD) 
   RNO,A.*
   FROM
  (
    SELECT  H.RAKEY,H.RCD,H.pkey,H.rkey,MIN(H.RCD) OVER (Partition by 
     H.PKey,K.rkey) Value
      FROM [SOURCE] H
      LEFT JOIN [SOURCE] K
      ON H.pkey = K.pkey AND H.rkey = K.rkey AND H.RCD <> K.RCD AND K.RCD IN 
      (6,8,9)
     WHERE H.RCD IN (6,8,9) 
   )A
   )H WHERE H.RNO = 1
```

Hi Gaur, I hope above query works for your question "What I am trying to do is, if PKey and RKey values are same for RCD 6 and RCD 8 and 9, I want to keep the details of RCD6 and discard rest of the details."